# content within an iframe in ios 7 mobile keeps scrolling to top always

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, ios7

I have an iframe displaying content wrapped in a div which has the scrolling set with css specified below

where CSS is 
      .Page {
        height: 100%;
         overflow: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
         position: relative;
       }
     iframe#FrameId{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
     }

The issue is that there is no handling for the scrolling on javascript and relies on the browser to handle scrolling.

if I scroll the content a little, once the scroll is done with,  the page jumps back to start of the page or to the top. Also if in case i click on any div or any other element in the iframe it scrolls to the top, basically it does not remember the scroll distance and always keeps scrolling to the top.

I tried disabling javascript on teh browser , i still see the same behaviour. How could i prevent it from scrolling to top? This happens only on ios 7 mobile. Is this a known issue on ios 7.?

any pointers to debug or solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a long long time ago, but I recently (10 minutes ago) came upon this problem aswell. The reason was the

```
overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

block.
When I changed all that to just

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

without the -webkit-overflow-scrolling at all, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been having the same problem.
With our software we use a single page with an iframe to load content with a side navigation bar on the left on the main page.

Everytime we scrolled past the first "fold" it would "flash" and then jump to the top.... 
I realised the problem was because a CSS change was being made somewhere on the page ( either within the iframe or on the main container page ).

By disabling the Jquery CSS changes we had and removing the CSS animations, I have now prevented the problem from occuring.

Comment: It would be better if you could add why this problem occurs and how your solution is going to help in this case.

Comment: When a CSS change was made within the browser frame, iOS reloaded the page as we believe it thought it was fresh content ( we still don't know why and we're still researching it :( ...  ).

By remove the CSS animations and the javascript CSS changes to elements, iOS doesn't think the page has reloaded so it doesn't auto scroll to the top.

Answer (score 0):

This tip helped me

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3838289

It's much easier to control overflowed divs than it is iframes, and the scrolling + blank content issues are working all the way back to iOS 4, where previously I wasn't even able to get the 2 finger scrolling to work (in iframes).

It goes something like this:

```
<iframe id="stupid-iframe" width="600" height="200" src="a-file.html"></iframe>


a-file.html:
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```